# What does "represent" mean in this context?

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

> The event attracts visitors and exhibitors from all over the country
>   as well as top experts from around the world **that are represented with
>   pavilions at the fair**. (https://www.tradefairdates.com/Securex-South-Africa-M13269/Johannesburg.html)

The bold part is confusing. It seems that "that" refers to "top experts", but how can experts be represented with pavilion? None of the dictionary meaning for "represent" seems to fit in this context. Does this mean "top experts who gather in pavilions at the fair"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a subtle grammar point here. It is just a rather clumsy sentence, with a poor choice of word. It probably means that exhibitors use pavillions to house their exhibitions.

I suppose you could say that a company that is exhibiting at the fair may be represented by a small team using one of the fair's pavillions. This justifies the use of the word "represent".